# How to extract initrd from ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso

Tags: disk-image, 20.04, initrd

I am trying to update a process used to remaster the Ubuntu 18.04 install image for 20.04 and running into a problem with extracting the initrd archive.
The command used is `cpio -id --no-absolute-filenames`. When I use this same command to extract the initrd image from the 20.04 image, it extracts `kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin` and stops.

Inspecting initrd file contents I can see a "TRAILER" section showing that there are multiple archives in the file. As suggested in other threads about cpio archives, I tried to extract the compound archive as such: `cat initrd | while cpio -id --no-absolute-filenames; do :; done`. In this case, the first entry extracts but then it has a bunch of "0 blocks" and doesn't extract anything else.

Does anyone know how this archive was created or how to extract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here -- the solution was to not unpack with Ubuntu version 20.04 using unmkinitramfs.

I created a bootable USB and booted my machine into Ubuntu 20 -- unmkinitramfs was then able to unpack the initrd.  I'm still finding my way around building a new bootable USB that doesn't autologin (and works correctly with casper-rw).

If you want to see more about what unmkinitramfs does, it's a bash script.  In a comparison between Bionic and Focal, Bionic does not supprt lz4 compression.

Comment: So is the point here that the version of unmkinitramfs shipped with versions previous to 20.04 not compatible with the format used?

Comment: That is indeed the issue. I needed the version shipped with 20.04.

Comment: when tried I got unmkinitramfs command not found message even though I have initram tools

Comment: $ apt-file search unmkinitramfs
initramfs-tools-core: /usr/bin/unmkinitramfs
initramfs-tools-core: /usr/share/man/man8/unmkinitramfs.8.gz
$

So the command is in the package initramfs-tools-core.

Answer (score 5):

/usr/sbin/update-initramfs calls /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs, which calls

```
cpio --quiet -R 0:0 --reproducible -o -H newc | lz4 -9 -l
```

where the lz4 is coming from /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf

reversing that into

```
cat /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic | unlz4 -9 -l | cpio -i -H newc
```

fails though.

```
cat /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic | file -
    /dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

keeps persisting it's a cpio archive, but

```
cat /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic | cpio -i -H newc
```

still ends up in the same AuthenticAMD.bin.
Maybe somebody else can build on this?

**Edit: nope. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511224/44864
The answer is**

```
 unmkinitramfs -v initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic .
```

Comment: unmkinitramfs also extracted GenuineIntel.bin and a junk directory named `.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc`, seemingly misunderstanding some metadata. It then errors with premature end of archive.

Comment: I suggest you look into the checksum of your downloaded copy of  ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso as I just downloaded it, and successfully unpacked the initrd.img from it with unmkinitramfs.

Comment: is the file you're looking at called "initrd.img"? I am looking at /casper/initrd.

Comment: Yes: https://pastebin.com/MqDVq6P8

Comment: I suggest you download http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-core_0.136ubuntu6_all.deb and extract it with 

    mkdir initramfs-tools-core
    cd initramfs-tools-core
    dpkg -x ../initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-core_0.136ubuntu6_all.deb .
    dpkg -e ../initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-core_0.136ubuntu6_all.deb
    ls -al ./usr/bin/unmkinitramfs
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 3595 Feb 18 02:19 ./usr/bin/unmkinitramfs

Comment: That edit must be bold and at the top of this answer!

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently creating a custom live CD, based on Ubuntu 20.04 live CD.
Everything is fine untill i tried to modify initrd.
I mean the initrd located in the casper directory of the iso.

The standard way to build the live cd ,as far as i understood, is first.

## Extract the iso in a separate directory

## Extract the squashfs file system in a separate directory

## Mount proc sys dev .. prior to make the chroot on the squashfs directory

# Make a chroot on squahfs dir

## And you can start modifying the squashfs filesystem for your needs.

# Make your modifications

## Prior to leave your chroot

# Do an update-initramfs (update-initramfs -k all -u)

## Rebuild the squashfs image

## Copy it into the iso dir

## Rebuild the iso image.

## One thing i noticed, update-initramfs does not modify initrd.

## In my case i was changing the plymouth theme.

- So, instead  i tried to create a new initrd, based upon the original initrd
  located under /casper.

mkdir temp;cd temp
unmkinitramfs ../initrd . # (casper)
mkinitramfs . -o ../initrd.new

## To me, this should create an initrd.new with the same size as the original.

## But its not the case ! the new one is bigger

## Otherwise, i tried an other method -----------------------

## Do

binwalk initrd
..
3492528       0x354AB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
3492864       0x354C00        LZ4 compressed data, legacy

## Just after the TRAILER line (get the lz4 size , here 3492864)

dd if=../initrd bs=3492864 skip=1 | unlz4 -c | cpio -id

## Now rebuild initrd

find | cpio -H newc -o | lz4 -c > ../initrd.partial.lz4

## And finally concatenate the microcode files and your new initrd (initrd.partial.lz) by

## Count is block size divided by 512

dd if=../initrd of=../initrd.microcode bs=512 count=6822

## Rebuild the newinitrd

cat ../initrd.microcode ../initrd.partial.lz4 > ../initrd.new

#---------------------------------------------------------

They do not have the same size eather!

It looks like that with focal, the initrd format has changed
somehow.
For sure lz4 compression has been added to focal, but there is
something else, but its not documented ....

Comment: Please, edit your answer... take your time and format properly.